# Can't call function of class multiple times

Tags: php, html

I'm getting an error with calling a function multiple times in a forEach.
Basically, I'm trying to grab the forums of categories, and I'm doing that by grabbing all of the categories, and forEach category I will grab the forums of that category. It works fine if I have just 1 category. I get no error. But if I have 2 or more, it gets the error.

Error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function grabForumsOfCategories() on a non-object in /home/dankkvgo/public_html/source/templates/forums_index.php on line 22

forums_index.php (just a snippet - line 22 is in there)

```
    $categories = $forum->grabCategories();
    if($categories == NULL) {
        echo '
            <div class="categoryForum">
                <p>No data retrived</p>
            </div>
        ';
    } else {
        if (is_array($categories)) {
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                try {
                    $category_id = $category["category_id"];
                    $category_title = $category["category_title"];
                    echo '
            <div class="forum-header"><h4>'.$category_title.'</h4></div>
                    ';
                    $forums = $forum->grabForumsOfCategories($category_id);
                    if ($forums == NULL) {
                        echo '
            <div class="categoryForum">
                <p>No forum data found in this category.</p>
            </div>
                        ';
                    }
```

my grabForumsOfCategories function in the forum class

```
public function grabForumsOfCategories($category_id) {
    $database = new database();

    $query = "SELECT *
              FROM forums_forums
              WHERE category_id='".$category_id."'";
    $result = $database->query_select($query);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Your $forum is null. Do var_dump($form) and see what you get. Enable xdebug extension for pretty print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like $forum is not an object every time. Try print_r($forum) above line 22 and make sure it is an object. The $forum object isn't instantiated every time it seems.

Comment: Above the first category now, I get this: forum Object ( )
and above the error, I get this: `Array ( [category_id] => 1 [0] => 1 [forum_id] => 3 [1] => 3 [forum_title] => Test Forum 2 [2] => Test Forum 2 [forum_description] => This is a test forum!!!!!! [3] => This is a test forum!!!!!! [forum_thread_count] => 0 [4] => 0 [forum_message_count] => 0 [5] => 0 [last_user] => None [6] => None [last_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [7] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00 [last_thread_id] => 1 [8] => 1 )`

Comment: I figured it out. In my forEach statement, I reassign the value of the forum to $forum instead of something different like $forum_row

Comment: Thanks for all the help